# join contains a syntaxis error

Tags: ms-access

I want to get the services that are filled and all the other services that are empty, but on excecute I get an message saying that

> join contains a syntaxis error

```
SELECT OverzichtID, ServiceID, Service.Beschrijving, [Service Aantal]
FROM Service.Overzicht
LEFT JOIN Service
ON Service_Overzicht.ServiceID = Service.ServiceID
```

Comment: C#? Where is your C#?

Comment: good question, were currently only working on getting it to work in acces i wil remove the tag

Comment: First, I think your table name in the `FROM` clause is wrong - it probably should be `Service_Overzicht` and not `Service.Overzicht`. Second, Access really likes parentheses -  try `ON (Service_Overzicht.ServiceID = Service.ServiceID)`

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks totaly missed this detail :D

Comment: I am not 100% sure but what ``ServiceID`` would this query pick?!? You should clarify it by specifing the table name ``Service.ServiceID``

Comment: So it's just a typo, then? if so, I suggest deleting this question.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Only Access likes to put parentheses in.  There's no need for them though - I usually have my SQL in Notepad++ so I can keep a clean copy of the the query.  If you look at a query the wrong way (usually Design View) it gets all het up and places parentheses everywhere and occasionally changes your joins around.

Comment: @RandRandom Good spot.  As `ServiceID` appears in both `Service_Overzicht` and `Service` tables then it needs to be fully qualified in the `Select` statement.  If it was unique there'd be no problem.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook It's been forever since I last worked with access. It's something I remember though wasn't sure it's going to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think your table name in the FROM clause is wrong - it probably should be `Service_Overzicht` and not `Service.Overzicht`. Second, Access really likes parentheses - try ON `(Service_Overzicht.ServiceID = Service.ServiceID)` – Zohar Peled 6 mins ago

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook this was an awnser by a guy in the comments i can't realy accept one of my comments as an awnser so this way i am giving him credit

Comment: This is not the proper procedure to be followed [while converting a comment to an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/4099593), kindly [edit] the post.